# how to return rows where there are duplicates in a column & where the duplicate values appear,they can't have same values in a diff column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Just wondering how I would write a query so I would only return rows where the `OrderID` appears more than once and the `Amount` is different.

| Amount | date | OrderID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 3-Nov-22 | 87 |
| 12 | 3-Nov-22 | 87 |
| 14 | 6-Nov-22 | 96 |
| 13 | 6-Nov-22 | 96 |
| 99 | 13-Nov-22 | 93 |
| 20 | 14-Nov-22 | 39 |
| 12 | 14-Nov-22 | 22 |

So I should only return the below output if using table above

| Amount | date | OrderID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 6-Nov-22 | 96 |
| 13 | 6-Nov-22 | 96 |

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COUNT` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT amount, "DATE", orderid
FROM   (
  SELECT amount, "DATE", orderid,
         COUNT(DISTINCT amount) OVER (PARTITION BY orderid) AS num_amount
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_amount > 1
```